# Setting up Netbeans 8.0.2 for use with Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, installation

I am trying to set up Netbeans 8 so that I can use Qt 5.4 on it (for c++). However, there does not seem to be any decent guide on how to set it up that way. On the netbeans website (https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html#qtinstall) only Netbeans 7 with Qt 4.6 is covered. Has anyone set it up like that? Or know about any guides on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the reason for downgrading your user experience from Qt Creator. It is good and available for almost any platform/bitness. On Windows it is somewhat better to debug with Visual Studio but on Linux you use same external debugger as available on the system/set for Creator.

Comment: The guide ist still valid for qt 5.4. If you have set up Qt correctly it will all be configured per default.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: I have worked a bit with QtCreator and I agree it's pretty good. I would just like to stick to Netbeans for now, but I will probably switch at some time in the future.

Comment: @ollo, I think I kind of messed up my netbeans installation by changing compilers recently and playing around with my configuration, will just have to do everything over I guess...but thanks anyways, will stick to the guide then

Comment: Ok, good luck. As i said before, if you have a correct installation of Qt, everything will be setup automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. install qt5 from qt official website
2. modify netbeans' qmake path to      qt creator's qmake(qmake5) path
3. build qt application in netbeans.

Comment: "modify qmake path" is in options/C++/Build tools. However, the official way of doing this is either setting your QT_SELECT environment variable, or set the default config (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf).